# Is there a script to update (almost) any Linux distribution?

Tags: linux, upgrade

I know of `apt-get update` and `yum update`, but I'm wondering what others there are to update other Linux OSes.

Could all these be combined into a script which could be run on any Linux distro?

Comment: AFAIK, there is no standardized update command. But you can always do something like [The Universal install script](https://xkcd.com/1654/) ;-)

Comment: @jofel That is the comic I was searching for! I'd love to see a list of commands like that which would update!

Comment: See the [pacman Rosetta](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman/Rosetta)...

Comment: The 'Universal Install Script' is also a 'Universal System Breaking Script' - it may or may not manage to install something but it will almost certainly break your system in the attempt.

Answer (score 1):

Let us start a list:

- Debian/Ubuntu/...: `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y`
- Suse/OpenSuse/... `zypper update`
- Gentoo: `emerge -u world`
- Red Hat/Fedora:  `dnf upgrade`
- Arch Linux/...:  `pacman -Syu`
- CentOS: `yum update`

<sup>This is a Community Wiki post, please add more!</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Each flavor of updates packages differently. Debian and Ubuntu flavors use apt-get and yum is used for CentOS (among others).

Comment: I already know both of these - I stated them as examples. Do you have any other examples?

Answer (score 0):

Another update method you can use is rpm. What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Do you have a project or just general knowledge?

Comment: General knowledge mainly.